# How to access webpack generated js file from index.html

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have a Flask app that is serving a template `index.html`, which in turn access a javascript file generated by webpack. The issue is that I am generating a hash for the webpack generated file, to prevent the browser from caching, and I cannot figure out how to access the webpack generated file, as the hash name can change. For example, if the webpack generates a file called `bundle-cdcf74127a4e321fbcf0.js`, I would not know the hash function `cdcf74127a4e321fbcf0` ahead of time, and so I could not access it in `index.html`.

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "static/bundle-[hash].js",
    },
    resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ['-loader']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                query: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(['static/bundle*.js'])]
};
```

The code used to call the webpack generated file in `index.html` is below (this code does not work, as it appears that asterisk search does not work in the file name here):

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle*.js"></script>
</body>
```

The flask app code goes like:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
@app.route('/')
def default():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How would I fix this code so that it serves the webpack generated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the  webpack plugin htmlWebpackPlugin, refer to https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration.

You can provide a html template for this plugin to inject the js files generated by webpack, pay close attention to these configuration options: `template` , `inject`, `chunks`, 'hash'.

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './index.html'
    favicon: './favicon.ico',
    filename: './dist/index.html'
    inject: 'body',
    chunks: ['vendor', 'app'],
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeComments: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you think you could give the code please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The HTML injecting done by this package seems to be causing the webpack to continuously refresh and generate new files. Do you know how to stop this from happening?

Comment: @Alex We need output this file to a specific directory for the outputs of 
 webpack compilation, and clean the directory before output using `CleanWebpackPlugin`. This is a common solution.

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing that, but the refreshing was still happening. Weird. I'll just ask in a new question. Thanks for your help!